# loading data from database to datatable through Ajax

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to fill my datatable from my database but I'm not passing through ajax.

as a consequence, my page  is charging very slowly and I can't charge more than 10000 row as I get

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

I want to paginate my page and send the result on page demand through ajax but i'm bit lost and can't figure how to do it

my HTML code:

```
<!-- /.panel-heading -->
<div class="panel-body" >
  <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID Commande</th>
        <th>Date Commande</th>
        <th>Numéro de commission</th>
        <th>Année</th>
        <th>Marque</th>
        <th>Modèle</th>
        <th>Finition</th>

      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      @foreach($Commandes as $Commande)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$Commande->RECID_NADIN}}</td>
        <td>{{$Commande->DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS}}</td>
        <td>{{$Commande->Num_Commission_NADIN}}</td>
        <td>{{$Commande->Annee}}</td>
        <td>{{$Commande->CodeMarque}}</td>
        <td>{{$Commande->CodeModele}}</td>
        <td>{{$Commande->CodeFinition}}</td>


      </tr>
      @endforeach

    </tbody>

  </table> <!-- /.table-responsive -->
```

My JS code :

```
// Les buttons de la table

$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  lengthChange: false,
  buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis' ]
  } );

  table.buttons().container()
  .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-sm-6:eq(0)' );

} );
```

and my Controller code

```
public function  index()
{
    $Commandes =  DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Commande_nadine')->paginate(10000);

    return view('detailsCommandes',compact('Commandes'));
}
```

Can anyone help with this ?

Comment: Does this work with a `paginate(15)` just to check ?

Comment: as @Mike said you can add `paginate(15)` in your controller and then fetch the data based on page button clicked from database

Comment: @Mike I'm already using paginate but there the number i'm fixing is sending the number of rows to retrieve

Comment: @SagarGautam how can I add the fetch based on page button ?

Comment: Yes but it might be 1000 rows takes to much memory that is why i am wondering if it works with 15 because if that also trows an error we have to look elsewhere.

Comment: When I use paginate(15) it shows just 15 entries

Comment: You can use this package https://github.com/freshbitsweb/laratables

Comment: Then a 1000 entry's is to much you will need to think of a different approach maybe you can utilize something like lazy loading

Comment: @Mike I believe I should paginate the page and load with ajax on demand but I'm a bit lost how to do it

Comment: Paginate with an amount that is still useful to the user and have buttons somewhere on the page to go to the next page or previous page. when the user clicks on it you load in the next page here is a more detailed description off the tools Laravel provides for this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination

Answer (score -1):

For datatables use this package [yajra/laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables)

Life became easier. :)

Comment: This is not really an answer and could have been a comment